# Win10: The network connection profile is corrupted. How to check the xml file?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, netsh

I want to import a xml files with wifi settings. I run:

```
netsh wlan add profile test.xml
```

And get the error message:

```
0x80420011 The network connection profile is corrupted.
```

But I get no line number where the xml file should be corrupted. Is there a tool which checks errors and give me more information?

This services are running:

```
wlansvc
EapHost
```

Comment: Create the profile on a system then EXPORT the .xml and edit it from there if necessary. Don’t try to create it from scratch. Also, trying to embed a WiFi password in an XML has other special considerations because by default the password is encrypted and not readable by another computer.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks for your answer. But I the wifi settings doesnt exist at another system before.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. If you know the settings for the WiFi you can create the connection trough the GUI then export the .xml for use elsewhere. If you don’t know the WiFi settings you can simply open the xml file and look. No reason to try to import a broken .xml in other words.